# Make matrix by subtracting each element of vector from other element of it

Tags: r, dataframe, matrix, vector

Consider the vector `a <- c(17.4, 17.2, 17.0, 16.9, 17.0, 17.4)`

How to build the following matrix:

```
 A <-    17.4-17.4   17.2-17.4  17.0-17.4  16.9-17.4  17.0-17.4   17.4-17.4
         17.4-17.2   17.2-17.2  17.4-17.2  16.9-17.2  17.0-17.2   17.4-17.2
         17.4-17.0   17.2-17.0  17.0-17.0  16.9-17.0  17.0-17.0   17.4-17.0
         17.4-16.9   17.2-16.9  17.0-16.9  16.9-16.9  17.0-16.9   17.4-16.9
         17.4-17.0   17.2-17.0  17.0-17.0  16.9-17.0  17.0-17.0   17.4-17.0
         17.4-17.4   17.2-17.4  17.0-17.4  16.9-17.4  17.0-17.4   17.4-17.4
```

I want to subtract all vector elements from the first element and store the result in the first row of matrix A, then subtract all vector elements from the second element and store the result in the second row of matrix A, and so on until the last element of vector an is reached.

The final result should be:

```
A <- 0.0   -0.2   -0.4   -0.5   -0.4   0.0
     0.2    0.0   -0.2   -0.3   -0.2   0.2
     0.4    0.2    0.0   -0.1    0.0   0.4
     0.5    0.3    0.1    0.0    0.1   0.5
     0.4    0.2    0.0   -0.1    0.0   0.4
     0.0   -0.2   -0.4   -0.5   -0.4   0.0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are a couple of options,

```
sapply(a, function(i) i-a)

matrix(Reduce(`-`, expand.grid(a,a)), ncol = length(a))
```

Answer (score 4):

Using outer

```
a <- c(17.4, 17.2, 17.0, 16.9, 17.0, 17.4)
t(outer(a,a,`-`))

     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
[1,]  0.0 -0.2 -0.4 -0.5 -0.4  0.0
[2,]  0.2  0.0 -0.2 -0.3 -0.2  0.2
[3,]  0.4  0.2  0.0 -0.1  0.0  0.4
[4,]  0.5  0.3  0.1  0.0  0.1  0.5
[5,]  0.4  0.2  0.0 -0.1  0.0  0.4
[6,]  0.0 -0.2 -0.4 -0.5 -0.4  0.0
```

Comment: Also `outer(a, a, FUN=\(x,y) y-x)` for a variation.